# Concatenate SQL fields where NULL not present

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Working with SQL Server 2008 R2

I tried to read all the other relevant postings, but did not see any that matched what I am trying to do.

I have two columns `Phone1` and Phone1Ext`

I just want to concatenate these columns as `Phone` in the format of `123-456-7890 x1234`.

I can do

```
Select phone1 + ' x' + phone1ext AS Phone from table
```

and get the result I need when `Phone1Ext` is not null. But if it is NULL I get

```
123-456-7890 x
```

and if `phone1` is NULL then I just get an `x`.

That is all expected based on the SQL line posted above.

I basically do not want to concatenate phone1 and phone1ext if phone1ext is NULL. I have tried various uses of `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` but have not had any luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only `phone1` you will get it, if both are `null` you will get empty string.

```
Select phone1 + ISNULL(' x' + phone1ext, '') AS Phone from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward:

```
select
case when ph2 is not null 
then ph1 + 'x' + ph2
else ph1
end
from
ph
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4850/1)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of you for your responses.  I had tried similar solutions to both of your answers prior to posting, but always go the unwanted x.  Then I had an epiphany.  The data I was concatenating was getting loaded from another system.  After looking closer, the data being put in was not a NULL value, but a '' or a series of blanks.  Hence they were never NULL!  I apologize for wasting your time, but wanted to post this in case anyone else ran across a similar result.  This is what I used to resolve it in my case:

SELECT 
  CASE WHEN Len(phone1ext) < 1 
  THEN Phone1 
  ELSE Phone1 + ' x' + phone1ext END AS Phone
FROM
  table

Thanks again.